# Google Scholar is assigning citations for my paper to a completely different paper

Tags: citations, google-scholar

My paper's arxiv id is 2008.09164. The title is "PyTorch Metric Learning".

When I search for the above arxiv id, [Google Scholar retrieves an entirely different paper](https://scholar.google.com/scholar_lookup?arxiv_id=2008.09164).

You can [see here](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=3657240428493512224&hl=en&as_sdt=0,33) that it erroneously thinks "PyTorch Metric Learning" and "Spatial semantic embedding network" are just versions of the same paper.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

**Edit**: This issue mysteriously resolved on its own after several months.